# How to test opened files in argparse using nose

Tags: python, testing, argparse, nose

So I'm trying to test my parser using `nose`. I have few arguments that are used for handling files using `type=argparse.FileType()`.

When I print out my parser's `parser_args()` function, my filename argument is of course specified, looks like this:

`Namespace(command_name='edit', filename=[<open file 'filename.p', mode 'r' at 0x108d4e1e0>])`

Now I want to test this using `nose` testing framework, specifically checking if the correct filename was indeed opened but I don't know exactly how.

When I do this (`test_sys_args` is modified `sys.argv` list for testing purposes):

`test_parser = test_parser_output(test_sys_args)
assert_equal(test_parser.filename, "[<open file 'filename.p', mode 'r' at 0x108d4e1e0>]")`

It doesn't work. I know I'm not doing this right because the memory address might be different each time the test is run and I'm also not sure if I can pass the `filename` object as a string like that.

Comment: 2 quick suggestions- the openned file object should have a name attribute.  Also check the test_argparse.py file to see how it tests Filetype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
assert_equal(test_parser.filename.name, 'filename.p')
assert_equal(test_parser.filename.mode, 'r')
```

Here's part of the section of the `test_argparse.py` file (from a recent development download):

```
class RFile(object):
    seen = {}

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if other in self.seen:
            text = self.seen[other]
        else:
            text = self.seen[other] = other.read()
            other.close()
        if not isinstance(text, str):
            text = text.decode('ascii')
        return self.name == other.name == text


class TestFileTypeR(TempDirMixin, ParserTestCase):
    """Test the FileType option/argument type for reading files"""

    def setUp(self):
        super(TestFileTypeR, self).setUp()
        for file_name in ['foo', 'bar']:
            file = open(os.path.join(self.temp_dir, file_name), 'w')
            file.write(file_name)
            file.close()
        self.create_readonly_file('readonly')

    argument_signatures = [
        Sig('-x', type=argparse.FileType()),
        Sig('spam', type=argparse.FileType('r')),
    ]
    failures = ['-x', '', 'non-existent-file.txt']
    successes = [
        ('foo', NS(x=None, spam=RFile('foo'))),
        ('-x foo bar', NS(x=RFile('foo'), spam=RFile('bar'))),
        ('bar -x foo', NS(x=RFile('foo'), spam=RFile('bar'))),
        ('-x - -', NS(x=sys.stdin, spam=sys.stdin)),
        ('readonly', NS(x=None, spam=RFile('readonly'))),
    ]
```

There's a lot of testing framework that I'm not showing, but you should get the idea.  The full file is at https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/ba5d7041e2f5/Lib/test/test_argparse.py

Comment: thanks that first bit is what I was looking for exactly. kinda missed that there are attributes to the file objects in the docs.

just another related question... how do I import the `test_argparse` module from `lib/test/` on my local machine? do I have to use `os.chdir` module to load it manually?

Comment: I've been pulling it from my own build of the development download (using `hg`).  That `test` directory might not be present in regular distributions.  On the mercurial link that I gave, click on `raw` on the right hand column to download a copy of that file.

Comment: I see, so probably including the file with my unit tests is probably the easiest way.